# ClientAbortException at application deployed at jboss with IE8 browser

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am having following exception for application deployed at Jboss, Browser is IE8

```
2012-03-19 09:17:12,014 WARN  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.jboss.web].         [localhost]] Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/internalError.jsp]
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:327)
```

It seems that browser closed the socket before server writes internalError.jsp to it.
Please suggest how to solve it , or atleast how I can hide this exception.

Thanks
Hikumar

Comment: Get used to those exceptions; they're common, and unavoidable given enough traffic.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot solve it. You cannot control whether the client will press Esc, or hastily click a different link, or close the browser, or have its machine crashed, etcetera, while your server is still handling the HTTP request/response.

You can "hide" it by a global filter (mapped on `/*`) which does something like this:

```
try {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
catch (ClientAbortException e) {
    // Ignore.
}
```

This however brings a servletcontainer-specfic dependency in your code. The filter in question would result in `NoClassDefFoundError` on a servletcontainer of a different make which doesn't use Tomcat specific `ClientAbortException`. You might want to check the class simple name instead. Make use of the advantage that it's a subclass of `IOException`:

```
try {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    if (!e.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("ClientAbortException")) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its coming even without pressing stop or closing browser or or hastily clicking a different link, May be something with Internet Explorer,  I will give a try to your solution, Still if you have any other solution which required very few changes i.e some configuration etc, please share                                Thanks

Comment: Are there instances where a ClientAbortException is thrown in which you wouldn't want to ignore it?  That is, would it be a good idea to at least log.debug or log.info it?